# svg clippath on a div that contain other divs (no css:clip-path)

Tags: html, css, svg

I am actually trying to make something that sounded very simple, but apparently it isn't

I have 2 div containing informations (text images etc). I want to put a clipping mask (circle shape) over those so if I put my mouse over it, it changes to a rectangle and reveal the whole content (that effect is pretty common no?) But apparently I can't even perform the task of puting a circle clipping mask over my divs

here's what I tried

```css
body {
  
  background-color:#000;
}
```

```html
<svg> 
        <defs>
        <clipPath viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="promopath" >
                <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="75" />
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        
        <use clip-path='url(#promopath)' xlink:href='#promo_bubble' fill='white' />
        
    </svg>
    <div class='promo_wrapper' id='promo_bubble'>
    
        <div class='promo_holder'><img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'></div>
        <div class='promo_holder'><img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'></div>
        
    </div>
```

[Codepen here if you want to play around](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGoXWW)

I can make a mask over a simgle image, but not for a whole container like in my example

I don't want to use clip-path because of edge and internet explorer support

Thanks for your help

Comment: you need to define `clip-path: url(#promopath);` on the element

Comment: "I don't want to use clip-path because of edge and internet explorer support"

Comment: you have defined clip-path in your code and I commented on how you have to use it

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for you VERY good answer! about the clip-path, the canvas tag clipPath have no links with clip-path. One can be a source of pathroute for the other, but that's it. you can make clippath like I did, if you use image inside the <image> tag of the svg object, but apparently not for an outside div like I wanted :( thanks for all anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider a trick using `border-radius` without any complex code or the use of SVG:

```css
.box {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#fff;
  transition:1s all;
}
.container {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid;
  transform:translate(calc(25px - 50%),calc(25px - 50%));
  transition:1s all;
}
img {
 float:left;
}
.box:hover {
  border-radius:0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin:0;
}
.box:hover .container{
  transform:translate(0);
}

body {
 margin:0;
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?image=1069" > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut et felis ligula. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi tempor pellentesque lacus id ullamcorper.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hehe, that's really good. I tried that solution but the content position was affected (obviously) I had to make the container move alongside a "wrapping box", that's clean I like it ;) thanks